# Get an array element by key php

Tags: php, arrays, encoding, key, json

I have an array of (many) arrays, encoded at different depths. The problem is that I know the key of the element I am searching for, but not the depth of the encoding. So for example it might be
    `Array ( [1] => Array ( [1] => Array ('abcd'  => 'a' ) )` or `Array ('abcd'  => 'a' )`
So is there any way to find that `abcd` key?

Comment: Loop through it recursively until you find it

Comment: Is there a quicker way? I have a lot of arrays.

Comment: What is the "array of (many) arrays" actually modelling? Knowing that would help others suggest data structures that may be better suited for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Colin it's an array resulted from decoding a json with json_decode

Comment: Yes, but what does the data **actually** represent?

Comment: @Colin it's data from facebook user accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function find_array_key($array,$keytofind){
 $found=false;
 if (is_array($array)&& $found==false){
   foreach($array as $key=>$value){
      if (is_array($value)&& $found==false){
        find_array_key($array,$keytofind)
      }else{ 
         if ($found==false && $key=$keytofind){
          $found=$value;
         }
      }
   }
   return $found;
 }
```

I didn't run this code to test it but it should be pretty close to a nice recursive function for what you are trying to do and returning the value of the key you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array_key_exists('abcd', $search_array))
```

Comment: well, yeah, but I want to find it and work on it, not only verify if it is existent